# Complete change and adding of content in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a web page that, when click activated, changes completely the content of a div element. I currently have some text and a video embedded in the div, and I want to remove that and add new content, such as links, more videos, etc. when a div button is clicked. I have not found much helpful information on this subject. Any help is greatly appreciated. [Here is a link to a fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/Render13579/WpKZG/)

```
<div id="content">
<p>"Text, text, more text."</p>
<h1>"Text"</h1>
<img src="#"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some code, or at the very least a link to a jsFiddle.

Comment: It's pretty hard to believe that you couldn't find any information. It's one of the most basic things you can do and it's covered in almost every tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
<div id="somecontent"><video ...><p>Video Caption</p></div>
```

You can use simple [DOM scripting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) to select the element and replace its contents:

```
<script>
  var element = document.getElementById("somecontent");
  element.innerHTML = "<audio><p>New Caption</p>"
</script>
```

You would then tie this replacement to the onclick event of an input or a link styled to look like a button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much oomlaut! Would it be helpful to me if I made that code into a function?

Comment: Not necessarily, unless you needed to repeat the functionality shared amongst additional elements.  You could simply assign the replacement as the actions of the onclick event of an element. Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mMWvS/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can help you a lot with stuff like this. For example, try jQuery's [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) methods. Then you can do something like this:

```
$('.my_button').click(function() {

    // this function gets executed when an element
    // with the classname '.my_button' gets clicked

    $('.my_div').html(
        'this contents get inserted in ' +
        'the element with classname ".my_div".'
    );

}
```

Installing jquery is as simple as including the jquery source before you call your own javascript code! Get the source [over here](http://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: +1 - Much better than using the onclick event of an input. Not sure why it was downvoted

Comment: Perhaps it was because the OP did not ask about using jQuery as the solution. Unsure.